# Could not import settings wsgi Django

Tags: python, django

I'm unable to get wsgi working on my production server. Running Django 1.4

This is my error.

**ImportError: Could not import settings 'Hera.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named Hera.settings**

My file project is in /srv/project/Hara/. Example of my file system is below...

```
    /srv/project/Hara/
      - manage.py

    /srv/project/Hara/Hara
      - settings.py
      - urls.py

    /srv/project/Hara/web
      - models
      - admin.py
      - views.py

/srv/project/Hara/apache
   - django.wsgi
```

django.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project/Hera')
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project/Hera/Hera')
print >> sys.stderr, sys.path
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Hera.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're appending the actual directory in your django.wsgi

```
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project/Hera')
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/project/Hera/Hera')
```

these are no longer applicable on your production site

`/srv/project/Hera` even better yet get the path in relation to the file something like:

`os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..')`

This way it doesn't matter where your code lives it will always get the

Comment: cool well thats seem to be now correct but the it now gives me a differnet error ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse':$

Comment: well at least you solved this one! you can create a new question with your new error